# A method of including one HTML file in another which I do not understand

Tags: html, jspinclude

I've come across an HTML file which includes this snippet:

```
  <div class="Header" role="banner">
    {% include 'header.html' %}
  </div>
```

I realise the purpose is to include the file 'header.html', but I've not come across this syntax before. Can someone explain it to me, please.

The site where I found it is:[here](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)

Comment: @Quentin: More self-explanatory is the fact that when someone asks a question, there is something he does not understand/needs help on - thus the asking. Now... what is the problem ?

Comment: As others have said below, it is not html.  It is part of a template language, that parses through the html and replaces the `{%""%} code bits with html dynamically.  There are several template languages that use those tags. Django, Twig, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I saw no mention of a template language on the otherwise helpful 'tutorial' site where I found this. I'll just use PHP include, which I do understand.

Answer (score 2):

I have been encountering this using symfony[PHP framework]. 
And as what I had understand from our class last semester, that the include() statement tells the Web server to go and get the header.html and include it in the page.

I have a link pasted down here. Hope it can help :)

http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a twig template:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html
The syntax would fit!

Answer (score -1):

That looks very much like [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/), a template language for Python - and it would very much do the same as a PHP include, which is to include the content from another template in the code.